# Editing dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm assigning values into a dictionary like this:

```
contacts = dict()

for company in companies_query:
    contacts[company.id] = dict()

for contact in contacts_query:
    contacts[contact.company_id][contact.id] = contact
```

So, for example I now have this key in the contacts dictionary `contacts["15"]["10"]` assuming there's a company with ID of 15 and a contact with ID of 10.

Now I need to create another for loop to add additional data to these contacts.

```
for sale in sales_query:
    contact = contacts[sale.company][sale.contact]
    contact.sale_count += 1
    contacts[sale.company][sale.contact] = contact
```

This doesn't work. For the second line it says there's a KeyError with a value of `<Contact: Contact object>`. `sale.company` is in this example 15, and the `sale.contact` is 10.

How do I edit the dictionary objects?

Comment: `second line` - Which one exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in the *whole `Contact()` instance object*, not the *`id` attribute value* of that object. You probably meant to use:

```
for sale in sales_query:
    contact = contacts[sale.company][sale.contact.id]
```

e.g. use the `sale.contact.id` attribute rather than use `sale.contact` directly.

Since you are manipulating the `Contact()` instance directly you don't need to assign back to the nested dictionary; the following 3 lines should suffice:

```
for sale in sales_query:
    contact = contacts[sale.company][sale.contact.id]
    contact.sale_count += 1
```

Note that using `dict()` to create an empty dictionary is not really common or idiomatic. Use the `{}` literal notation instead:

```
contacts = {}

for company in companies_query:
    contacts[company.id] = {}

for contact in contacts_query:
    contacts[contact.company_id][contact.id] = contact
```

You can build the `contacts` mapping with a dictionary comprehension too:

```
contacts = {company.id for company in companies_query}

for contact in contacts_query:
    contacts[contact.company_id][contact.id] = contact
```

Comment: Same issue with `sale.company.id`

Comment: @Eric: not necessarily; the `KeyError` shows that a `Contact()` instance is the problem; that's the second key being passed in. That would only happen if the `sale.company` attribute was a valid id, not some instance of a `Company()` class.

Comment: Thanks for this, didn't even think of that. :)